# Android program to connect to Facebook: LoginActivity has leaked window

Tags: android, android-facebook

Here is the basic program, provided by Facebook itself - to connect an android app to facebook:
But I seem to get an error:
 `Activity com.Facebook.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@DecorView@40512630 that was originally added here:`

Following things have been tried:

- I've verified my `keyHash`.
- I've verified my `Android.xml`
- I've looked for more inputs on the forum.

Any suggestions ???

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.facebookconnectionapp;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("Facebook Activity", "Before opening session");

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.i("Facebook Activity", "Checking if session open");

                if(session.isOpened()){

                    Log.i("Facebook Activity", "Session is open");
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Log.i("Facebook Activity", "Inside GraphCallback");

                            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            textView.setText(user.getUsername());
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                    Log.i("Facebook Activity", "Session not open");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.facebookconnectionapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.facebookconnectionapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are connected to the internet. If you aren't, you will get this error.

Comment: Looks like it. Must be an bug in the facebook sdk itself.

Answer (score 3):

`leaked window` means that your `Activity` is closed (finished) and there is any other `Dialog` (Progress/Alert) is still open.

Be sure to `dismiss` the `Dialog`s before calling `finish()` or catch `Exception` so that `Activity` doesn't get closed.

It has nothing to do with `key hash` and `Manifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the code after 1 day ... it worked. I would still like to figure out what happened that day !

Comment: Still I would suggest you to use `Exception Handling` for those lines of codes which caused `leaked window`...